Необходимо в звпросе SQL заменить все определённые значения на другие
К примеру есть таблица со столбцами 'ID' , 'NAME' , 'time'
В столбце ID есть значения "1" "2" "3" , каждому из этих значений предписано имя где 1 - вверх , 2-вниз , 3-вперёд
Необходимо заменить все id на имена

Читайте про оператор CASE.

Возможный дубликат вопроса: Замена значения по словарю при SELECT

Вероятно примерно так (с использованием case):
WHEN ID = 1 THEN 'вверх'
WHEN ID = 2 THEN 'вниз'
WHEN ID = 3 THEN 'вперёд'


не могу разобраться, напишите пожалуйста пример полного кода если не сложно

Ставлю перед фром и получаю такую ошибку "Expected one of: token, Comma, FROM, PREWHERE, WHERE, GROUP BY, WITH, HAVING, WINDOW, ORDER BY, LIMIT, OFFSET, SETTINGS, UNION, EXCEPT, INTERSECT, INTO OUTFILE, FORMAT, end of query. (SYNTAX_ERROR) (version 23.4.1.1943 (official build))"

SELECT
CASE
WHEN ID = 1 THEN 'вверх'
WHEN ID = 2 THEN 'вниз'
WHEN ID = 3 THEN 'вперёд'
WHEN ID = 4 THEN 'назад'
END AS NAME,
time
FROM
your_table_name;

Редактируйте ответ пожалуйста, а не пишите комментариями )
